# Concatenate two columns with different names

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables, joined on one column, I want to concatenate one of the columns with different names into the same column, I have tried this

I want `whstocks.warehouse` to be concatenated with `brnstocks.brachcode`.

current result (no 900 brachcode from whstocks)

```
brachcode | varint | stock
---------------------------
201       |24601121| 2
204       |24601121| 3
197       |24601121| 4
```

Desired result (bring 900 from whstocks.warehouse into branchcode)

```
brachcode | varint | stock
---------------------------
201       |24601121| 2
204       |24601121| 3
197       |24601121| 4
900       |24601121| 400
```

```
SELECT  brnstocks.branchcode , brnstocks.varint , SUM(brnstocks.retail)
FROM dbo.brnstocks
INNER JOIN dbo.whstocks
ON brnstocks.varint = whstocks.varint
GROUP BY brnstocks.branchcode, whstocks.warehouse
        ,brnstocks.varint
        ,brnstocks.retail
        ,whstocks.stock
HAVING (SUM(brnstocks.retail) > 0)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  You have left out some information, such as:  which columns do you want to concatenate?  In addition, your `select` only refers to one table, so why are two tables being used?  And why all the columns in the `group by`?

Comment: Two tables are used as the data is in two seperate tables. One is warehouse and one is shop stocks.

Comment: Have you tried a `UNION` on the two tables before doing the `GROUP BY`? What is the structure of `warehouse`

Comment: Will try that now Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    P.branchcode , P.varint , SUM(P.retail)
FROM
(SELECT  
    branchcode , varint , retail
FROM dbo.brnstocks
UNION
SELECT  
    branchcode , varint , retail
FROM dbo.whstocks
) AS P

GROUP BY P.branchcode , P.varint
HAVING (SUM(P.retail) > 0)
```

Assuming that `whstocks` has the same fields as `brnstocks`. If not, substitute the matching fields from `whstocks`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already grouping by both, you should be able to concatenate them using the + operator.

```
SELECT  whstocks.warehouse + brnstocks.branchcode [WarehousePlusBranch], brnstocks.varint , SUM(brnstocks.retail)
FROM dbo.brnstocks
INNER JOIN dbo.whstocks
ON brnstocks.varint = whstocks.varint
GROUP BY brnstocks.branchcode
        ,whstocks.warehouse
        ,brnstocks.varint
        ,brnstocks.retail
        ,whstocks.stock
HAVING (SUM(brnstocks.retail) > 0)
```

Comment: That actually puts both together like below! So 900 and 062

900062 217983600 16.0000